# Pass variable value from form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Say I got a HTML form like below and want to pass the values in the textfields to JS variables.

```
<form name="testform" action="" method="?"
<input type="text" name="testfield1"/>
<input type="text" name="testfield2"/>
</form>
```

I've only passed values to variables in PHP before. When doing it in javascript, do I need a method? And the main question, **how is it done?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples:

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('name_of_input_control_id').value;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#name_of_input_control_id").val();
```

Basically you are extracting the value of the input control out of the DOM using Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Note how the controls in OP’s example don’t have an ID though …

Comment: True. OP will have to add an ID to his/her input controls.

Comment: My point is: not necessarily. Using a name is just fine, and since form elements need a name anyway (at least when they also communicate via the form with a server), why not use that?

Comment: Depends what the OP wants to do with that value.  Maybe he/she wants to do some browser side validation or some fancy UI/UX based on the input.

Comment: That doesn’t change anything.

Comment: Thank you for your input and Konrad for your additional insight

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your "submit":

```
var input = $("#testfield1").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

the answers are all correct but you may face problems if you dont put your code into a document.ready function ... if your codeblock is above the html part you will not find any input field with the id, because in this moment it doesnt exist...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var input = document.getElementById('name_of_input_control_id').value;
}, false);
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var input = $("#name_of_input_control_id").val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a `method` or an `action` attribute if you're simply using the text fields in Javascript

Add a `submit` button and an `onsubmit` handler to the form like this,

```
<form name="testform" onsubmit="return processForm(this)">
    <input type="text" name="testfield1"/>
    <input type="text" name="testfield2"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then in your Javascript you could have this `processForm` function

```
function processForm(form) {
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
    // parse text field values into an object
    var textValues = {};
    for(var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
        if(inputs[x].type != "text") {
            // ignore anything which is NOT a text field
            continue;
        }

        textValues[inputs[x].name] = inputs[x].value;
    }

    // textValues['testfield1'] contains value of first input
    // textValues['testfield2'] contains value of second input

    return false;  // this causes form to NOT 'refresh' the page
}
```